# C++ Secure Connection to DB

Tags: c++, database, c, reverse-engineering

I have always had this question in mind and hopefully one of you will know the answer.

I have heard over the Internet / News that Software Coding like C++ is reversible, which as far as I understood by that is that others can find your source code from the already-compiled .exe.

How do you secure a database connection then? I mean, how to you keep the database information and every of its mysql queries private.

```
mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "user", "passwd", NULL, 0, NULL, 0)
```

For example, in the code above how would you keep the information user and password secure when the code is reserved and user has been able to access the source code?

Thanks,

EDIT: same applies to C or any Software developing code.

Comment: Add a third layer, a server which does all the querying and talks to the database. Search for REST.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is: You should not pass binaries with hard coded usernames and passwords to a user but allow the user to enter those to some form of configuration. If they should talk to your system you should confiure one user account per user.

When storing the password in a configuration file you can store it encrypted (this could also be done when hard coding, but that's a bad practice) and decrypt when needed. Of course a malicious user can try to identify the encryption algorithm and passphrase, preventing this can only be done by not storing at all or using hardware-based vrypto systems (maybe a dongle)

In the end the question is: How hard do you want to make it? Somebody who has (especially physical) access and enough "need" will always find a way.

Comment: But, what I meant is that, how do you keep the code secure if someone manages to get the source code? Password encryption would work for making password secure only. What about the source code?

Comment: You can't completely. What you can do is make disassembling more complicated by asking the compiler to do more optimisations or stripping symbols and other techniques.

Comment: Is it using a Web server to handle queries more recommendable than writing myqsl_ queries into the programme?

Comment: This can only be answer by saying "it depends", but usually , yes, it makes sense to provide a more high level abstraction layer. Why? - A higher level API reduces security relevant vectors, allows you to make modifications without breaking clients, allows more fine-tuned access control and verification, ....

Comment: If you had to share an application made in C++, will you use a Webpage to handle all queries or would you include them in the C++ source code?

Comment: As said: It depends. As also said providing higher level APIs usually is a good thing. If you have a more precise case having an extra question might make sense. For this question this discussion (which fills bookshelves) leads too far away.